# How to prevent users to drop files in my shared document?

Tags: copy-and-paste

I am sharing documents using SharePoint but users sometimes drop big documents inside slowing access time. So is there any way to enforce policy to do not embed any documents, then just put warning text in document **Please do not drop anything here**?

Comment: Do you want to prevent all user from adding documents? If so, create unique permissions for the library and give contribute rights to the the particular group or user.

Comment: Is it for all users. What will be permission name? I see only permissions of using certain formatting elements only.

Comment: You must be at least Site Owner to perform permission management. Please take a look at: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-HA102833689.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In Central administration, you can set maximum file size limits. This will prevent users from uploading large files across the web application.

You can also limit who has access to upload files to your library by managing permissions on the library so that only the appropriate individuals can add documents.